# AutoHotkey RegExReplace with math

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I am trying to change all instances of a number in an xml file. The constant 45 should be added to the number.

Temp is the following text:

```
<rownum value="1">
  <backupapplication>HP Data Protector</backupapplication>
  <policy>AUTDR12_Daily</policy>
  <policytype>FileSystem</policytype>
  <dataretained>31</dataretained>
  <fullbackup>7</fullbackup>
  <backuptime>0.17</backuptime>
  <retentionperiod>Short</retentionperiod>
  <peakmbps>11</peakmbps>
  <backupcategory>Fulls &amp; Fulls</backupcategory>
</rownum>
<rownum value="2">
  <backupapplication>HP Data Protector</backupapplication>
  <policy>AUTP_Appl_Monthly</policy>
  <policytype>FileSystem</policytype>
  <dataretained>268</dataretained>
  <fullbackup>91</fullbackup>
  <backuptime>2.31</backuptime>
  <retentionperiod>Long</retentionperiod>
  <peakmbps>12</peakmbps>
  <backupcategory>Fulls &amp; Fulls</backupcategory>
</rownum>
```

I tried the following code:

```
NeedleRegEx = <rownum value="(\d+)">
Replacement = <rownum value="($1+45)">
Temp := RegExReplace(Temp, NeedleRegEx, Replacement)
```

But this changes it into

```
<rownum value="1+45">
```

while I want

```
<rownum value="46">
```

How do I do this in AutoHotKey?

Comment: i dunno , if thats a file it might be possible to do it using `awk` or `sed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RegEx aren't designed to evaluate mathematical expressions. There are some languages, in which you can use a replacing function that can do dynamic replacements (e.g. JavaScript). But no such luck in AHK.
Using RegEx for the purpose of parsing XML documents isn't good practice anyway. I suggest using an XML parser instead. For AHK, you can utilize a COM object of `MSXML2.DOMDocument`. Here's an example (and further references) of how to use it: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/56987-com-object-reference-autohotkey-v11/page-2#entry367838.
What you want to do is parse your XML to a DOM document and loop over every `rownum` tag. Now, you can retrieve the `value` attribute, increment it, and overwrite the attribute with the new value.

### Update

To the code you've posted in the comments: There were some minor mistakes and one big mistake. The big mistake was trying to parse non-valid XML. You can check your XML files by feeding them to a [formatter/validator](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html#ad-output). The `loadXml()`method will return `false` if there was a parsing error. The method `obj.saveXML()` does not exist. If you want to retrieve the document's string representation, simply access its `xml` property: `obj.xml`. If you want to save it to a file, there's the built-in method `save(filepath)`.

Here's my suggestion for a clean approach (yes, you CAN use meaningful variable names!):

```
doc := ComObjCreate("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
if(!doc.loadXml(xmlString)) {
    msgbox % "Hey! That's no valid XML!"
    ExitApp
}

rownums := doc.getElementsByTagName("rownum")
Loop % rownums.length
{
    rownum := rownums.item(A_Index-1)
    value := rownum.getAttribute("value")
    value += 45
    rownum.setAttribute("value", value)
}

doc.save("myNewFile.xml")
```

Comment: I tried following your suggestion and created the following AHK script: http://chopapp.com/#jtglca45 . It does not seem to work though. Any comments/ideas?

Comment: @kasper I'd like to save your code but that site won't even let me copy the code without line numbers. Please post it on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).